# Cannot retrieve event I display in my browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to access to an event I display in my browser console that looks like this :

[image: Event I display in my browser]

I tried :

```
$('#gridDossiers').on('check.bs.table', function (row , $element) {
            console.log("row", row)
            console.log("Data from row :", row.currentTarget.jQuery2240240399670067494632.bootstrap.table)  
        })
```

But I get an error : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bootstrap')**
I think because of the "." between bootstrap and table!

Is there a way to retrieve this event?

Comment: `["bootstrap.table"]`. You have to use subscript notation when the property name contains special characters.

Comment: Just discovered that the 'jQuery2240240399670067494632' changes every time the event triggers so I think it's impossible to retrieve it

Comment: You should probably be using something in the Bootstrap API, not accessing internal properties like this.